# django create a form from list

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Lets say I have a list

```
mylist = ['name', 'username']
```

And I want to create a form from this list:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    for field in mylist:
        field = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Its not giving me the form for name and username.
How can I create a form from list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fields are kept in `self.fields` dictionary:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)       
        for field in mylist:
            self.fields[field] = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```